# Apps Script WebApp not handling parameter consistently

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a standalone google apps script that is used to display a data table and edit entries. The two pages are loaded using parameters at the end of the url address.
I have two parameters possible {edit, entry}.
The first parameter edit can only have one value "form" to tell that I need to access the edit page and the entry number is used to identify the table entry to be edited.

```
function doGet(e) {
  // Retrieve and process any URL parameters, as necessary.
  Logger.log(e.parameter.edit);
  Logger.log(e.parameter.entry);
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  
  if (e.parameter.edit == "form" & e.parameter.entry) {
    Logger.log("edit");
    return EditEntry(e.parameter.entry);
    
  } else {
    Logger.log("table");
    return LoadTable();
  }  
}
```

As you can see, the doGet function is straight forward and will serve two different other functions depending on the parameters.
My issue is that depending on the entry value, it migh not work be well processed by the if function.
For example the url with "?edit=form&entry=4444" give this log:

> *Infos    form Infos  5555 Infos  {entry=5555, edit=form} Infos   edit*

the url with "?edit=test&entry=5555" give this log:

> *Infos    test Infos  5555 Infos  {entry=5555, edit=form} Infos   table*

**BUT** the url with "?edit=form&entry=4444" give this log:

> *Infos    form Infos  4444 Infos  {entry=4444, edit=form} Infos   table*
> And does not serve me what I expect.
> As I can see from the log it is not that the entry doesn't exist (it does..) but it is not even trying to look for it.
> So my question is why on earth  `if (e.parameter.edit == "form" & e.parameter.entry)` is TRUE for ?edit=test&entry=5555 and FALSE for ?edit=test&entry=4444

NB: I could discard the `edit` parameter as it can only take one value, and then there is no bug at all, but my development path will requireme to have other parameter to pass,so I need it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.edit == "form" && e.parameter.entry) {
    return EditEntry(e.parameter.entry);
  } else {
    return LoadTable();
  }  
}
```